# EF CF keeps wanting to drop database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6 Code First to develop a Database and Application.  It seems that each day I start testing the application (all the data flows through a WCF service) I get an error stating that the Database cannot be dropped because it is in use.

I am using Database Migration, I have set the configuration constructor to:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
}
```

I am not sure where else to look.

Comment: Do you have an `<entityFramework>` section in your web.config? Is there a `<databaseInitializer>` specified there for the appropriate `<context>`?

Comment: Similar to what Brad said, you have anything in Global.asax that would be calling Database.SetInitializer?

Comment: I have a databaseInitializer point to this class:  

public class AddMoveChangeInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AddMoveChangeContext>
    {

        protected override void Seed(AddMoveChangeContext context)
        {
            
        }
    }